# Toast.LENGTH_LONG

Tags: android

I am new to android, and I am understanding some already developed code. I am confused about `Toast.LENGTH_LONG`. I searched for it, and what I got is - Toast is like an alert message which will disappear after some time, but am not getting it further clearly, 
so please anyone can help me?

Comment: I'm not sure what more you want. `Toast is like an alert message which will disappear after some time,` is quite clear, isn't it?

Comment: actually I am confused about LENGTH_LONG for what time it will appear, my wild guess is- time might be the toast string length, is this so?

Comment: No, it is a system default. you have a 'long' time and a 'short' time. It is a limited system, but meant to be that way. Don't use it for things the user _needs_ to see. If you need more control you probably don't want a toast anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toast is a temporary view that runs in ui thread for a limited time and disappears automatically . Assume it as smoke comes out of toaster in real world . IT disappears after some time . This is how toast works in android . To implement it user .

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

LENGTH_SHORT   Show the view or text notification for a short period of time.This time could be user-definable. This is the default.

LENGTH_LONG Show the view or text notification for a long period of time.This time could be user-definable.

Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) for further information.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

exactly it is time period for toast still any doubt than please prefer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

Comment: This is incorrect. The two values possible are LENGTH_LONG which is 1 and LENGTH_SHORT which is 0. They are treated as flags not durations.

Answer (score 0):

Take always a look to the official android documentation.
Here are all informations you need: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html

```
LENGTH_LONG     Show the view or text notification for a long period of time.
LENGTH_SHORT    Show the view or text notification for a short period of time.
```